# How to make SSHPASS not wait for the result of the sent command and disconnect instead?

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, sshpass

I am using SSHPASS to configure a Linux based device through a temporary IP for automation purpose.

```
sshpass -p $TARGET_password ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $TARGET_username@$TARGET_IP 'bash -s' < $configfile
```

I am sending a script with a bunch of commands, the last one being configure the permanent IP.

As soon as the script changes the IP, it hangs because it lost the session with the temporary IP.

So is it possible to send the command that changes the IP and immediately disconnect not waiting for any return.

Answer (score 2):

Make it disconnect *before* it changes the address. For example, make the last command run in background with the `&` operator, maybe something like this:

```
( (sleep 1; ip addr change ...) &)
```

---

There's no good way for SSHPASS to know whether it's not receiving any ACK because the command succeeded (and the IP changed), or whether it's not receiving any ACK because the command packets haven't reached the server *at all* (due to network issues). In the former case you want it to disconnect, but in the latter case it should keep retransmitting the unacknowledged packets.

Comment: thanks @user1686 for your prompt reply.
I tried it, "command & exit" but it still wait for the return.

Comment: @AJN Then how about just have the whole config file run as a `NOHUP` with `&` at the end and just exit? Meaning just run `nohup (config file contents) & && exit` The first `&` sends it to the background and the `&&` sets it so `exit` runs. Your process runs in the background on the machine and doesn’t hang up, but your script exits before that ever happens. The command completes and you are gone.